# Demonstrating Equivalent GCDs

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

I am attempting to prove that:

$gcd(n^2-100n, 2n+1) = gcd(n-100, 201)$

To do so, I'm making use of the Euclidean algorithm, but I'm not getting to any result that I find particularly useful in demonstrating the equality. When I divide the terms on the LHS, I arrive at a remainder of $\frac{201}{4}$, whereas the RHS yields $\frac{n}{201} - \frac{100}{201}$. I have other incomprehensible calculations that I don't think would add much to the post. Any suggestions would be appreciated, I'm sure the solution is something rather trivial that I'm botching up.

Comment: Note that, as stated in the $6$'th [GCD property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Properties), "If $m$ is any integer, then $\gcd(a + m\cdot b, b) = \gcd(a, b)$".

Comment: You are doing the right thing (although there are slicker ways to proceed). I too get $\frac{201}{4}$ for the LHS, but **your calculation on the RHS is wrong** : $201$ goes into $n-100$  $\frac{n}{201}$ times and leaves a remainder of $-100$. So with the convention that GCDs are monic both LHS and RHS evaluate to $1$.

Comment: As explained in the dupe such gcds can be evaluated *mechanically* by a  twist on the Euclidean algorithm 

$$\begin{align} 
(2n\!+\!1,n^2-100n) 
&= (2n\!+\!1,\,\color{#c00}2^2(n^2-100n))\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ (2n\!+\!1,\color{#c00}2)=1\\
&= (2n\!+\!1,\,(\color{#0a0}{2n})^2-200(\color{#0a0}{2n}))\\
&= (2n\!+\!1,\,(\color{#0a0}{-1})^2\!-200(\color{#0a0}{-1}))\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#0a0}{2n\equiv -1}\pmod{2n+1}\\
&= (2n\!+\!1,\,201) \end{align}$$  

Generally this shows $\,(2n\!+\!1,p(n)) = (2n\!+\!1, 2^k p(-1/2))$ where $k = \deg p,$ and $\,p(x)\,$ is any polynomial with integer coef's.

Comment: Similarly if $\,(a,b)=1\,$ then $$\bbox[8px,border:1px solid #c00]{(an+b,\,p(n)) \,=\, (an+b,\,a^kp(-b/a))}\,$$ and we can compute $\,a^k p(-b/a)\,$  by a fraction-free method by scaling by $a^k$ as we did above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\gcd(ab,c) = \gcd(b,c)$ whenever $\gcd(a,c) = 1$. Now note that $n^2-100n = n(n-100)$ and check $\gcd(n,2n+1)$.

Comment: That's clever, thanks!

Comment: @scoopfaze, you are welcome. It's a trick worth remembering whenever you do gcd calculations.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque, I answered the question before this was tagged as duplicate.